# How to print a function in python?

Tags: python

i have following code and want to print the functions.

```
answer = "'Tis but a scratch!"

def black_knight():
    if answer == "'Tis but a scratch!":
        return True
    else:             
        return False        # Make sure this returns False

def french_soldier():
    if answer == "Go away, or I shall taunt you a second time!":
        return True
    else:             
        return False
```

I have tried it with:

```
x = black_knight()
y = french_solider()
print (x,y)
```

but it won't work. Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Doesn't work how? This prints `True False`; if you want something different you will need to explain what.

Comment: Edit your title not funktion

Comment: @Dan No it doesn't

Comment: You misspelled the second function's name. You should change `y = french_solider()` to `y = french_soldier()`

Comment: You can use `return answer == "'Tis but a scratch!"` instead of the whole `if else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

It's a misspelled issue.

Instead of :

```
y = french_solider()
```

Fix it to:

```
y = french_soldier()
```

Comment: You should preferably vote to close the question when they are typos